# Custom UIStoryboardPopoverSegue wont work under iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I've implemented a custom story board segue which is working fine under iOS 6 but nothing happens in the simulator under iOS 5.1.
The problem is that the popoverController is always nil under iOS 5.1?!

```
@implementation PopoverFromRectSegue  

-(id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
             source:(UIViewController *)source
        destination:(UIViewController *)destination {

  if(self = [super initWithIdentifier:identifier
                             source:source
                        destination:destination]) {
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)perform {
    UIPopoverController *popCtrl = ((UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)self).popoverController;

    id controller = [self sourceViewController];
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]] && [controller respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverRect)]) {
    [popCtrl presentPopoverFromRect:[[controller performSelector:@selector(popoverRect)] CGRectValue] inView:[controller view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
  }
}
@end
```

Any help/hint is appreciated.

Edit:
Just made new sample project. It seems that under iOS5.1 the popoverController is not set
for custom UIStoryBoardSegues.
What else can I do.
The normal popover requires an anchor but a prototype tableView cells is not accepted (failure during compile) and I couldn't find a way to modify the rect the popover is presented from.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my workaround.
**PopoverFromRectSegue.h**

```
@interface PopoverFromRectSegue : UIStoryboardPopoverSegue
  @property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popoverCtrl;
@end
```

**PopoverRectFromSegue.m**

```
#import "PopoverFromRectSegue.h"
@implementation PopoverFromRectSegue

- (void)perform
{
  UIPopoverController *popCtrl = ((UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)self).popoverController;

  // under iOS 5.1 the popoverController iVar is not set
  // so we have to use our own one
  if (nil == popCtrl) {
    popCtrl = self.popoverCtrl;
  }

  id controller = [self sourceViewController];
  if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]] && [controller respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverRect)]) {
    [popCtrl presentPopoverFromRect:[[controller performSelector:@selector(popoverRect)] CGRectValue] inView:[controller view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
  }
}

@end
```

In my prepareForSegue method I do the following.

```
    if (isPad) {
      self.popoverCtrl = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
      if (nil == _popoverCtrl) {
        self.popoverCtrl = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:[segue destinationViewController]];
        ((PopoverFromRectSegue *)segue).popoverCtrl = _popoverCtrl;
      }
      self.popoverRect = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:[self.myTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
  }
```